# Would it be possible to call a function in every instance of a class in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Game {
public:
  virtual void Tick() {
    // Somehow call the tick in every instance of "Object" or any derived class
  }
};

class Object : public Game {
public:
  std::string Name;
  Object(std::string name) : Name(_name){
   
  }
  void Tick(){
    // Do something every update
    std::cout << this->Name << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
 Game* game = new Game();
 
 Object* obj1 = new Object(), *obj2 = new Object();
 
 while (1) {
  // A game loop that will call all the classes
  game->Tick();
 }

 
 
}
```

Would it be possible to call a function in the "Game" class that calls it in every instance of the "Object" class?

Like Game->Tick() which would call the tick function in obj1 and obj2

I have made one previously where all of the objects were stored in an std::vector but I felt this was too slow and I was wondering if this way was possible, should I stick to the array method of updating each object?

I am just curios as I would like to make a simple game just to try it out

Comment: You need to register the object in your game one way or the other. Since you have polymorphic object, you can simply have a `std::vector<Object*>` (or probably `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`) in your `Game` and use it to call the `Tick()` on all objects.

Comment: calling methods on elements in a `std::vector` should not be any slower than doing the same with elements in an array. It is not clear what the problem was with code you did not post.

Comment: First of all, is `Object` really a `Game`? Remember the *is a* relationship of inheritance. Secondly, do you really need pointers to the `Object` instances?

Comment: I'll stick to the std::vector way because that seems to be the easiest

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps the `Game` object should have a container of (**smart**) pointers to all objects? Then it could use a simple loop to call the `Tick` function of all the objects.

Comment: I'm very new to polymorphism so I'm just playing around with it honestly

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. If you want the ability to do something like this you will need to implement it yourself, by keeping track of every instance of this class, in some fashion, and then you can do this trivially. There are many different approaches that can be used to approach a rather broadly-scoped task of this nature. This is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you probably do not want that.

First, you are using inheritance between `Game` and `Object`. Inheritance is a *is a* relation. Are your really sure that all `Object` instances are also `Game` instances?

If you want to call a method on a bunch of instance, then you need a container for those instances and you will iterate on it. If you really want the container to know all instances, you could make it a static member or the class, have the constructor to add a pointer to the object to the container and the destructor to remove it. Without more details I would use a `std::set<Object *>` here because insertion and removal are simple.

But care must be taken to add a custom copy constructor, because the default copy constructor would not add a newly created object to the container (thanks to @Caleth for pointing it out)

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

// An abstract class for classes having a Tick() metho
class Tickable {
public:
    virtual void Tick() = 0;
    virtual ~Tickable() {}
};

class Game: public Tickable {
public:
    virtual void Tick();   // definition will follow Object definition
};

class Object : public Tickable {
    static std::set<Object*> instances;  // THE container
public:
    std::string Name;
    Object(std::string name="") : Name(name) {
        instances.insert(this);          // add here
    }
    // do not forget a custom copy ctor...
    Object(const Object& other) : Name(other.Name) {
        instances.insert(this);
    }
    void Tick() {
        // Do something every update
        std::cout << this->Name << std::endl;
    }
    ~Object() {
        instances.erase(this);      //and remove there
    }
    // only publicly give a const reference to the internal container
    static const std::set<Object*>& getInstances() {
        return instances;
    }
};

void Game::Tick() {
    // Somehow call the tick in every instance of "Object" or any derived class
    for (Object* obj : Object::getInstances()) {
        obj->Tick();
    }
}
std::set<Object*> Object::instances;   // required per One Definition Rule...

int main() {
    Game* game = new Game();

    Object* obj1 = new Object("foo"), * obj2 = new Object("bar");

        // A game loop that will call all the classes
        game->Tick();
}
```

It will give as expected:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Rule of 5 for `Object`?

Comment: @Caleth You are right: the `Object` class needs custom copy and/or move constructors. I'll add them in a while...